# Top panel in vertical dual-monitor layout

Tags: wingpanel

I want to have the following layout. Secondary monitor on top of the primary (laptop) monitor. However the top panel moves to the upper one (secondary-monitor).

Is there any way to fix the position to the primary monitor (or any given one) the same way as it is possible with the plank?

[image: Layout]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that it is not. This is the associated bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1413158